# Need only One row with Numberweek

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need return only one row where `Weeknumber` will be same I choose in where condition.

```
CREATE TABLE #WeekExpense
( 
    WeekNumber VARCHAR(20),
    WeekDayName VARCHAR(50), 
    Expense MONEY
)

INSERT INTO #WeekExpense
VALUES
( 'Week05','Monday', 20 ),
( 'Week05','Tuesday', 60 ),
( 'Week05','Wednesday', 20 ),
( 'Week05','Thurusday', 42 ),
( 'Week05','Friday', 10 ),
( 'Week05','Saturday', 15 ) ,
( 'Week05','Sunday', 8 ),
( 'Week04','Monday', 29 ),
( 'Week04','Tuesday', 17 ),
( 'Week04','Wednesday', 42 ),
( 'Week04','Thurusday', 11 ),
( 'Week04','Friday', 43 ),
( 'Week04','Saturday', 10 ) ,
( 'Week04','Sunday', 15 ),
( 'Week03','Monday', 10 ),
( 'Week03','Tuesday', 32 ),
( 'Week03','Wednesday', 35 ),
( 'Week03','Thurusday', 19 ),
( 'Week03','Friday', 30 ),
( 'Week03','Saturday', 10 ) ,
( 'Week03','Sunday', 15 )
```

Here I need select for each week (03,04,05) avg,sum,count,min,max

```
SELECT  WeekNumber ---- I want there was Week03
        COUNT(Expense) asdasd,
        AVG(Expense) AvgOfExpense,
        SUM(Expense) SumOfExpense,
        MIN(Expense) MinOfExpense,
        MAX(Expense) MaxOfExpense
FROM #WeekExpense
WHERE WeekNumber = 'Week03'
```

Comment: Learn how to ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). You obviously encountered an error - so acknowledge that fact and include the complete error message in your question. And don't add confusion by using abbreviations like `each week (03,04,05)` - those are not values found in your table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to group your result set by WeekNumber. This can be done as follows:

```
SELECT  WeekNumber, ---- I want there was Week03
        COUNT(Expense) asdasd,
        AVG(Expense) AvgOfExpense,
        SUM(Expense) SumOfExpense,
        MIN(Expense) MinOfExpense,
        MAX(Expense) MaxOfExpense
FROM #WeekExpense
WHERE WeekNumber = 'Week03'
GROUP BY WeekNumber
```

Here's some docs for GROUP BY:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

The w3schools one is a good intro (as usual), but not as much detail.

Comment: thankssss mateee..